# Quick and easy Slicehost slices

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can anyone point me to an article with the best way to quickly setup a Slicehost slice with Rails/Git from scratch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Slicehost has [a number of useful articles](http://articles.slicehost.com/rails) on how to set up rails.  [These capistrano recipes](http://github.com/josh/slicehost/tree/master) might also come in handy.

Answer (score 2):

If you arent' experienced linux/apache admin, you can follow a sequence of 6-8 of pickled onions posts: apt-get update, SSH, iptables, mysql, ruby, gems, rails, apache, mod_rails

Here's the sequence for [ubuntu intrepid](http://github.com/GavinJoyce/rubyjobs/tree/master)

---

Here's what i used for Hardy

http://articles.slicehost.com/2008/4/25/ubuntu-hardy-setup-page-1

http://articles.slicehost.com/2008/4/25/ubuntu-hardy-setup-page-2

http://articles.slicehost.com/2009/2/2/ubuntu-intrepid-installing-mysql-with-rails-and-php-options

http://articles.slicehost.com/2008/4/25/ubuntu-hardy-installing-apache-and-php5

http://articles.slicehost.com/2008/4/28/ubuntu-hardy-apache-config-layout

http://articles.slicehost.com/2008/4/28/ubuntu-hardy-apache-configuration-1

http://articles.slicehost.com/2008/4/28/ubuntu-hardy-apache-configuration-2

http://articles.slicehost.com/2008/4/30/ubuntu-hardy-ruby-on-rails

(This is a good minimal sequence. I would recommend spending more time learning iptables, denyhosts, how to blacklist IP's and summarize logfiles to lock the server down).

Answer (score 1):

I just did a slicehost installation (Ubuntu Hardy/RoR)

1. [Install Ruby](http://articles.slicehost.com/2008/4/30/ubuntu-hardy-ruby-on-rails)
2. [thin installation](http://articles.slicehost.com/2008/5/6/ubuntu-hardy-thin-web-server-for-ruby) (your RoR server)
3. [Nginx installation](http://articles.slicehost.com/2008/5/27/ubuntu-hardy-nginx-rails-and-thin) (The web server/vhost/proxy)
4. [Watch git tutorials here - they are great!](http://gitcasts.com/posts/page/1)

Thin/Nginx is very easy to set up compared to Apache/Mongrel, and uses less memory. Apache wins in some performance test, but uses more memory.

Answer (score 0):

Rails core team member Josh Peek has some [Capistrano recipes for setting up and deploying to Slicehost](http://github.com/josh/slicehost/tree/master).